# I have an error when I'm trying to copy a texture with SDL_RenderCopy, in C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

This is my .cpp file:

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include  <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

bool runningOnEmpty = false;
const char* title;
int xpos, ypos, width, height;
bool fullscreen = false;
SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;

void init(){
  int flags = 0;
  if(fullscreen){
    flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
  }

  if(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)){
    std::cout << "Sdl initialised!!\n";

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
    if(window){
      std::cout << "window created!!\n";
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if(renderer){
      std::cout << "renderer created!!\n";

      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    runningOnEmpty = true;
  } else {
    runningOnEmpty = false;
  }
  if(TTF_Init()==-1) {
    std::cout << "cannot init TTF: " << TTF_GetError() << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "TTF initialized!" << "\n";
  }
}

void render(){
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  TTF_Font* rFont = TTF_OpenFont("./fonts/roboto.ttf", 20);
  if(!rFont){
    std::cout << "Cannot open font: " << TTF_GetError() << "\n";
  }
  SDL_Color White = {0, 0, 0};
  SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(rFont, "Score: ", White);

  if(surfaceMessage == NULL)
    std::cout << "Cannot make surface!" << SDL_GetError() << "\n";

  SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);

  SDL_Rect mr;
  mr.x = 50, mr.y = 50, mr.w = 100, mr.h = 100;

  if(Message = NULL)
    std::cout << "Cannot make texture!" << SDL_GetError() << "\n";

  if(SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &mr))
    std::cout << "Cannot render text!" << SDL_GetError() << "\n";

  SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void clean(){
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
  SDL_Quit();
  std::cout << "Game cleaned!\n";
}

void handleEvents(){
  SDL_Event event;
  SDL_PollEvent(&event);
  switch(event.type){
  case SDL_QUIT:
    runningOnEmpty = false;
    break;

  default:
    break;
  }
}

int main(){
  title = "Test";
  xpos  = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;
  ypos  = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;

  width = 800, height = 900;
  fullscreen = false;

  init();
  render();

  while(runningOnEmpty){
    handleEvents();
  }

  clean();

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles without error, and when I run the executable it renders a white window, with no text on it(even if it should have some text).

The error comes when I try to use SDL_RenderCopy, and as I acknowledged using SDL_Error(), apparently the texture is invalid, even if I check it before using it.

This is the exact thing that I get in the console when running the code:

```
Sdl initialised!!
window created!!
renderer created!!
TTF initialized!
Cannot render text!Invalid texture
Game cleaned!
```

Comment: enable as many compiler warnings as you can! this would have caught the issue right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if(Message = NULL)` is an assignment, not comparison, so your previous value of `Message` is lost and it is `NULL` after that, and that result is used as logic value (`NULL` == `0` == `false`, for that matter). Enabling compiler warnings should produce a message pinpointhing this specific problem, e.g. `-Wall` for gcc gives

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   if(Message = NULL)
```

To compare values, use `==` operator.

Also your texture goes out of scope without DestroyTexture, which is clearly a resource leak.

Comment: Thanks! How dumb I am =)))) I was wondering what could have been the problem for so long, and couldn't figure it out!

Comment: Well that's exactly why compilers have warnings for common problems - we all make "simple" mistakes, but at least some of them can be spotted automatically. gcc and clang are particularly good at that, with MSVC cl far behind, but still being able to catch at least something. So, if you use gcc/clang, using at least `-Wall` (or with `-Wextra` and some others, if you can) can save a lot of time.